# Django Images for individual users not showing

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have page with a list of all the users in my system. Each user in the lists displayed with three things: 1. their profile picture, 2. their first name, and 3. their user type. However, while the profile picture does show, it does not show the correct one corresponding to that specific user. Instead, it shows the profile picture of the currently logged in user for every user on the site.

user profile_list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for users in userprofile_list %}
        <a class="user-profile-link user-card" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' users.pk %}">
            <img class="profile-pic" src="{%if user.userprofile.profile_pic%}{{user.userprofile.profile_pic.url}}{%endif%}">
            <p class="user-card-name">{{ users.first_name }}</p>
            <p class="user-card-type">{{ users.user_type }}</p>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

A picture of what is happening:
[image]

Instead of a picture of me for every user, their individual profile pictures should be displayed, even though I am the one logged in.

Comment: You have `for users in userprofile_list`, but refer to `user.userprofile.profile_pic.url` (plural vs. singular). `User` then is probably coming from one of the context processors.

Comment: `user` is whoever is logged in, and is passed to the context in every template, that I know of.  That means it would be you, and your typo there is what is causing the users pictures to all be you.  This doesn't answer your question, but it should clarify why it is happening.  You have another problem that doesn't seem obvious to me with the information given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo need add `s` because your loop variable is `users` and looks like you need to remove `userprofile`

```
src="{%if users.profile_pic %}{{ users.profile_pic.url }}{% endif % }"
<!--          ^^^                    ^^^ -->
```

Comment: updated the unswer try it, if not help you, add your models to the question

Comment: Yeah I think that did the job, thanks. Why did I have to take out `userprofile`?

Comment: in my mind `userprofile_list` it is the list of `UserProfile` model so `profile_pic` it is an property of it.